# Content can be hidden using CSS flexbox with overflow

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

I'm new to using flex boxes in CSS. But this seems very nice for alignments and free space distribution between components!

Today I have a problem I don't manage to solve. Thanks in advance for your help.

Here is a codepen to illustrate the problem quickly :
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BYdzqR

```css
#example1 .wrapper, #example1bis .wrapper{
  justify-content: space-between;
}
#example2 .wrapper, #example2bis .wrapper{
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
#example3 .wrapper, #example3bis .wrapper{
  justify-content: space-around;
}
#example4 .wrapper, #example4bis .wrapper{
  justify-content: center;
}
#example4 .content .group, #example4bis .content .group {
margin: auto;
}

#example1, #example2, #example3, #example4{
  height: 600px;
}
#example1bis, #example2bis, #example3bis, #example4bis{
  height: 300px;
}

.root{
/*   background: lightblue; */
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: flex;
}
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 20px;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  height: 100%;
}

/* ----------------------------- */
/* Top */
/* ----------------------------- */
.top {
  padding: 20px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}

/* ----------------------------- */
/* Content */
/* ----------------------------- */
.content {
  padding: 10px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
.content .group {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
}
.content h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: red
}

/* ----------------------------- */
/* Bottom */
/* ----------------------------- */
.bottom {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  border-top: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<h1>Reference : without overflow</h1>
<p>Different kind of free space allocation. What I would like is something like #2 ("justify-content: space-evenly"). Eventually #3 ("space-around") or #4 ("center", with "margin: auto" on items)</p>
<div class="root">
  <div id="example1" class="box">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="top">
        #1 : space-between
      </div>
      <div class="content wrapper">
        <div class="group">
          <h2>Section 1</h2>
          <p>blah</p>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
          <h2>Section 2</h2>
          <p>blah</p>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
          <h2>Section 3</h2>
          <p>blah</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bottom">
        footer
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="example2" class="box">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="top">
        #2 : space-evenly
      </div>
      <div class="content wrapper">
        <div class="group">
          <h2>Section 1</h2>
          <p>blah</p>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
          <h2>Section 2</h2>
          <p>blah</p>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
          <h2>Section 3</h2>
          <p>blah</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bottom">
        footer
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="example3" class="box">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="top">
        #3 : space-around
      </div>
      <div class="content wrapper">
        <div class="group">
          <h2>Section 1</h2>
          <p>blah</p>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
          <h2>Section 2</h2>
          <p>blah</p>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
          <h2>Section 3</h2>
          <p>blah</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bottom">
        footer
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="example4" class="box">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="top">
        #4 : center
      </div>
      <div class="content wrapper">
        <div class="group">
          <h2>Section 1</h2>
          <p>blah</p>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
          <h2>Section 2</h2>
          <p>blah</p>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
          <h2>Section 3</h2>
          <p>blah</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bottom">
        footer
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h1>Problem : with overflow</h1>
<p>The problem is when there is not enough free space to display all the content. "overflow-y: auto" should allow to scroll to see all the content, but this is not the case with #2, #3 and #4... ("Section 1" title hidden)</p>
<div class="root">
  <div id="example1bis" class="box">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="top">
        #1bis : space-between = OK
      </div>
      <div class="content wrapper">
        <div class="group">
          <h2>Section 1</h2>
          <p>blah</p>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
          <h2>Section 2</h2>
          <p>blah</p>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
          <h2>Section 3</h2>
          <p>blah</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bottom">
        footer
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="example2bis" class="box">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="top">
        #2bis : space-evenly = KO
      </div>
      <div class="content wrapper">
        <div class="group">
          <h2>Section 1</h2>
          <p>blah</p>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
          <h2>Section 2</h2>
          <p>blah</p>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
          <h2>Section 3</h2>
          <p>blah</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bottom">
        footer
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="example3bis" class="box">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="top">
        #3bis : space-around
      </div>
      <div class="content wrapper">
        <div class="group">
          <h2>Section 1</h2>
          <p>blah</p>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
          <h2>Section 2</h2>
          <p>blah</p>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
          <h2>Section 3</h2>
          <p>blah</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bottom">
        footer
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="example4bis" class="box">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="top">
        #4bis : center
      </div>
      <div class="content wrapper">
        <div class="group">
          <h2>Section 1</h2>
          <p>blah</p>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
          <h2>Section 2</h2>
          <p>blah</p>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
          <h2>Section 3</h2>
          <p>blah</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bottom">
        footer
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Explanation :

I have some "boxes" (in fact they are modals) with a header, a footer, and some content between. I would like the header and footer parts always visible, and the content scroll if too big to display all.

In the content part, I have several "sections" (groups of other items).
I would like these "groups" to be equidistant from each other (ie: free space between grows when it can. I saw the flex container property `justify-content: space-evenly` that is exactly what I want.

This is fine when I have to much space to display my content. I takes all the available space with "harmony".

The problem is when I have many content and that it cannot be displayed. So all the "groups" will be sticked. fine. I put my content an `overflow-y: auto` so it will scroll in that case.

But with `justify-content: space-evenly`, I can't access the top of my content even when the scroll is at the top. It is OUTSIDE the content wrapper...

Same problem with `justify-content: space-around` or `justify-content: center` + `margin: auto` on the flex items.

The only working solution is `justify-content: space-between`, but unfortunately this is not the behaviour I want...

What can I do to achieve this and have access to all my content if there is a scroll ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`space-evenly` is a new property and won't work cross browsers (read more at the end).

As of today, you could use [auto margin](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins), where in this case all `group` items get a bottom auto margin, and the first also get a top auto margin.

That will generate the output you asked for.

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eVEExm)

Stack snippet

```css
body {
  margin: 0; 
}
.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.content {
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}
.content .group {
  margin-bottom: auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background: yellow;
}
.content .group:first-child {
  margin-top: auto;
}
.content h2 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.top, .bottom {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="top">
    auto margin
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="group">
      <h2>Section 1</h2>
      <p>blah</p>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
      <h2>Section 2</h2>
      <p>blah</p>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
      <h2>Section 3</h2>
      <p>blah</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    footer
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Even with `space-evenly` one also need to add yet another new feature, a new `keyword` called `safe`, though it is still [a working draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-align-3/#overflow-values), and not many (if any) browsers support it yet.

And the reason is, when using e.g. `justify-content`, [the overflow](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-align-3/#overflow-values), in this case when using `column` direction,  will be at both the top and bottom of the flex container.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks a lot your solution works like a charm! And thanks again for the great explanations.